# paypal payflow pro cancelling recurring billings

Tags: paypal

> I am using Payflow pro for recurring payment using the below code, as
>   per my knowledge this code return profileid.
>
> Do I need to store this profile id in a database so that user can
>   cancel the subscription in the future.
>
> please do reply with your useful comments .
>
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  PayPalRequest = "TRXTYPE=R"
>                       + "&TENDER=C" //C - Credit card
>                       + "&ACTION=A"
>                       + "&OPTIONALTRX=A"
>                       + "&TERM=0" //0 - recuring never stops
>                       + "&COMMENT1=Advertisement package subscription (Recurring)"
>                       + "&PROFILENAME=" + viewModel.PackageName + "-" + UserID
>                       + "&USER=" + AppProperties.PayPalFlowUser
>                       + "&VENDOR=" + AppProperties.PayPalFlowVendor
>                       + "&PARTNER=" + AppProperties.PayPalFlowPartner
>                       + "&PWD=" + AppProperties.PayPalFlowPassword
>                       + "&AMT=" + viewModel.PayAmount
>                       + "&CURRENCY=" + AppProperties.CurrencyId
>                       + "&ACCT=" + viewModel.CardNumber //card number
>                       + "&EXPDATE=" + viewModel.ExpirationMonth + viewModel.ExpirationYear.Substring(2, 2)
>                       + "&START=" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString(AppConstants.ddMMyyyy)
>                       + "&PAYPERIOD=" + GetPayFlowPeriodVariables(viewModel);
>
> PayflowNETAPI PayflowNETAPI = new PayflowNETAPI();
>
> ### string PayPalResponse = PayflowNETAPI.SubmitTransaction(PayPalRequest,PayflowUtility.RequestId);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would store the profile ID in your database along with the order/customer info so you can always lookup details about it in the future or update the status accordingly.

The following API's could be used to manage profiles using their ID.

- [ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/)

Comment: Hi Andrew, can you please help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843245/payflow-paypal-recurring-payment-expdate-validation